# How do I return the index number for nth occurrence of a given value?

Tags: python, indexing

Keeping the question as generic as possible - I have a list of values and need to return the index of the nth occurrence of a specified value...

```
list = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
occurrence = 5
value = 1
```

So I am looking for the index of the 5th time that the value 1 occurs. In the example above, the returned value should be 11.

'occurrence' and 'value' are variables that need to be set by the user

## EDIT

Thanks for the help guys, been playing around with various options and came up with this one

```
valList = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
occurrence = 5
value = 1

count = 0
rowIndex = -1

for val in valList:
    if count < occurrence:
        rowIndex += 1
        if val == valCR:
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an efficient version:

```
def nth_index(sequence, n, value):
    i = -1
    for _ in xrange(n):
        i = sequence.index(value, i + 1)
    return i

 lst = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
 print nth_index(lst, 5, 1) # 11
```

This behaves like the built-in `index` and raises a ValueError when the value is not found or `n` is too large:

```
 print nth_index(lst, 55, 1) # ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

FTR, timings:

```
import timeit, itertools

lst = range(1000) * 5
value = 0
occurrence = 5

print timeit.timeit(lambda: [i for i,elem in enumerate(lst) if elem==value][occurrence-1], number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(lambda: next(itertools.islice((i for i,elem in enumerate(lst) if elem==value), occurrence-1, occurrence)), number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(lambda: nth_index(lst, occurrence, value), number=1000)
```

--

```
0.52188706398
0.416564941406
0.117225885391
```

Comment: i've marked the other repy as the 'answer' but thanks for this as i'm a fan of while/for loops because i find them easier to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> mylist = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
>>> occurrence = 5
>>> value = 1
>>> [i for i,elem in enumerate(mylist) if elem==value][occurrence-1]
11
```

Or, the `itertools` way:

```
>>> next(itertools.islice((i for i,elem in enumerate(mylist) if elem==value), occurrence-1, occurrence))
11
```

Comment: It should be `occurrence-1`, and careful about the IndexError.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks for the bugreport. Good point (clearly, the coffee hasn't kicked in yet)